# Getting the used select statement has different number of columns

Tags: mysql, join

how do I get the output of this query in a single table

```
select 
  common_name, category, size, container, flower_image, price 
from 
  biocard
join 
  inventory_listing 
union 
select 
  common_name, count(*) as total_quantity 
from
  biocard 
group by 
  common_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you. Just add your own ON conditions instead of my  `biocard.pk = inventory_listing.fk`. I didn't know what to join your tables on.

```
SELECT
    common_name,
    category,
    size,
    container,
    flower_image,
    price,
    bio_Count.total_quantity
FROM 
    biocard join inventory_listing
ON
    biocard.pk = inventory_listing.fk LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                                                    common_name,
                                                    count(*) as total_quantity 
                                                FROM
                                                    biocard 
                                                GROUP BY 
                                                    common_name) bio_Count
ON
    bio_Count.common_name = biocard.common_name
```